# ClassLoader.getResources() returning duplicates

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, classloader

I have a Spring-Boot application which is running as a war file, i.e. I'm starting it with 
`java -jar my.war`

One library (prettyfaces) calls `ClassLoader.getResources("xx")` and gets duplicate results, which results in runtime errors. Basically all matching resources are returned twice, once with a `jar:file:/path/to/war!embeddedJar!xx` URL and once with a `jar:war:file/path/to/war*embeddedJar!xx`URL.

After debugging, it looks like the first version of the URL is returned by the `URLClassLoader`, the second one by the Tomcat `WebAppClassLoaderBase`.

Is there a solution or configuration flag to make these two return the same URL, or to somehow get the canonical URLs from them? Are these URLs both correct, or is this a bug in Tomcat?